# Regex to find when a colon is not proceeded by quotes OR a comma is not preceded by quotes

Tags: json, regex

I have been researching Regex for 2 hours and not able to figure out how to find the first and third record:

```
"name":value",
"name":"value",
"name":"value,
```

I have tried many things my latest failed attempt:

```
[!^:"]|[^",]
```

Can anyone provide any pointers on how I can achieve this?
Thinking about this, what would be ideal is to be able to search for records in my data where the character " is found 4 times.

Comment: What language are you using? What is your intended replacement?

Comment: Do you mean "when a colon is not **followed** by quotes" ?

Comment: Not an answer, but if you have broken JSON on your hands, just go back to the source and fix it.  Not much reason to try to detect it yourself, let the parser fail on its own.

Comment: I am using JSON, I want to find data where either the first quotes and/or both quotes are missing on the value.

Comment: @deucalion0: Does `[:,](?!"|$)` work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example data, you might use an alternation to match either starting or ending with a `"`

```
"[^"\r\n]+":(?:[^"\r\n]+"|"[^\r\n"]+)(?:,|$)
```

In parts

- `"[^"\r\n]+"` Match from `"` till `"` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `:` Match `:`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[^"\r\n]+"` Match any char except `"`, then match `"`
  - `|` Or
  - `"[^\r\n"]+` Match `"` followed by matching any char except `"`
- `)`
- `(?:,|$)` Match a comma or assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/riVmZh/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it did not quite work for me, could you provide some help to search each line and find those that contain 4 quotes?

Comment: @deucalion0 This pattern will match a whole line which had 4 quotes https://regex101.com/r/DE1GWt/1

Comment: Or try using anchors on the initial pattern `https://regex101.com/r/bDLH1q/1`

Comment: Excellent thank you, this works for me and is a great help. Quick question, do you know if there is a way to reverse this pattern so that it finds all strings that do not have 4 quotes? This could be very useful. Thanks!

Comment: @deucalion0 To reverse it you could use a negative lookahead https://regex101.com/r/XO6Zhp/1